# JNLP Autoupdate when saved to desktop location

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start, auto-update

I have a JNLP file that has the following set:

```
    <shortcut online="false">
        <menu submenu="Startup"/>
        <menu submenu="AnotherFolder"/>
</shortcut>
```

This creates a shortcut in the Startup folder and 'AnotherFolder'. I also have this set:

```
<update check="always" policy="prompt-update"/>
```

Now since i added the shortcuts my JNLP refuses to update and check back on its jnlp path:

```
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://www.website.com" href="http://www.website.com/start.jnlp">
```

Any ideas why my WebStart app isn't updating properly, if ever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is a Java 1.6 feature.

write

```
<jnlp sepc=6.0+"
```

and it's OK.